# python: find first string in string

Tags: python, string, match

Given a string and a list of substrings I want to the first position any substring occurs in the string. If no substring occurs, return 0. I want to ignore case.

Is there something more pythonic than:

```
given = 'Iamfoothegreat'
targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'other']
res = len(given)
for t in targets:
    i = given.lower().find(t)
    if i > -1 and i < res:
        res = i

if res == len(given):
    result = 0
else:
    result = res
```

That code works, but seems inefficient.

Comment: What behavior you expect from a input like `"duuuuuh"` and find `"uu"` in that ?

Comment: @Rockybilly "first position any substring occurs in the string"

Comment: @foosion How about my pattern matching solution. Should be fast, cause I think regex has a very fast implementation

Comment: @foosion, what is your typical input like?

Comment: padraic, the example is a close enough

Answer (score 2):

I would not return 0 as the could be the start index, either use -1, None or some other value that is not a possibility, you can simply use a try/except and return the index:

```
def get_ind(s, targ):
    s = s.lower() 
    for t in targets:
        try:            
            return s.index(t.lower())
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return None # -1, False ...
```

If you want to ignore case for the input string also then set `s = s.lower()` before the loop.

You could also do something like:

```
def get_ind_next(s, targ):
   s = s.lower() 
   return next((s.index(t) for t in map(str.lower,targ) if t in s), None)
```

But that is doing at worst two lookups for each substring as opposed to one with a try/except. It will at least also short circuit on the first match.

If you actually want the min of all then change to:

```
def get_ind(s, targ):
    s = s.lower()
    mn = float("inf")
    for t in targ:
        try:
            i = s.index(t.lower()) 
            if i < mn:
                mn = i 
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return mn   

def get_ind_next(s, targ):
   s = s.lower()
   return min((s.index(t) for t in map(str.lower, targ) if t in s), default=None)
```

The `default=None` only works in python >= 3.4 so if you are using python2 then you are going to have to slightly change the logic.

Timings python3:

```
In [29]: s = "hello world" * 5000
In [30]:  s += "grea" + s
In [25]: %%timeit
   ....: targ = [re.escape(x) for x in targets]
   ....: pattern = r"%(pattern)s" % {'pattern' : "|".join(targ)}
   ....: firstMatch = next(re.finditer(pattern, s, re.IGNORECASE),None)
   ....: if firstMatch:
   ....:     pass
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.11 ms per loop
In [18]: timeit get_ind_next(s, targets)
1000 loops, best of 3: 691 µs per loop

In [19]: timeit get_ind(s, targets)
1000 loops, best of 3: 627 µs per loop

In [20]:  timeit  min([s.lower().find(x.lower()) for x in targets if x.lower() in s.lower()] or [0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.03 ms per loop

In [21]: s = 'Iamfoothegreat'
In [22]: targets = ['bar', 'grea', 'other','foo']
In [23]: get_ind_next(s, targets) == get_ind(s, targets) ==  min([s.lower().find(x.lower()) for x in targets if x.lower() in s.lower()] or [0])
Out[24]: True
```

Python2:

```
In [13]: s = "hello world" * 5000
In [14]:  s += "grea" + s

In [15]: targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'other']
In [16]: timeit get_ind(s, targets)1000 loops, 
best of 3: 322 µs per loop

In [17]:  timeit  min([s.lower().find(x.lower()) for x in targets if x.lower() in s.lower()] or [0])
1000 loops, best of 3: 710 µs per loop

In [18]: get_ind(s, targets) ==  min([s.lower().find(x.lower()) for x in targets if x.lower() in s.lower()] or [0])
Out[18]: True
```

You can also combine the first with min:

```
def get_ind(s, targ):
    s,mn = s.lower(), None
    for t in targ:
        try:
            mn = s.index(t.lower())
            yield mn
        except ValueError:
            pass
    yield mn
```

Which does the same job, it is just a bit nicer and maybe slightly faster:

```
In [45]: min(get_ind(s, targets))
Out[45]: 55000

In [46]: timeit min(get_ind(s, targets))
1000 loops, best of 3: 317 µs per loop
```

Comment: Make sure you indent properly.

Comment: To properly ignore case, you will need to lowercase `s` as well.

Comment: @ekhumoro, I had a note at bottom of my answer but I added it in altogether

Comment: I think the OP wants the lowest starting index among all target strings (i.e. the same solution with `min` instead of `next`)

Comment: eskaev is correct.  This returns the first item in the list that matches rather than the lowest starting index.

Comment: @foosion, did you read the answer, *If you actually want the min of all then change to:*, I added how to get the first of any the match and also the actual index of the lowest matched substring.

Answer (score 2):

## Use regex

Another example just use regex, cause think the python regex implementation is super fast. Not my regex function is

```
import re

given = 'IamFoothegreat'
targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'other']

targets = [re.escape(x) for x in targets]    
pattern = r"%(pattern)s" % {'pattern' : "|".join(targets)}
firstMatch = next(re.finditer(pattern, given, re.IGNORECASE),None)
if firstMatch:
    print firstMatch.start()
    print firstMatch.group()
```

**Output is**

```
3
foo
```

If nothing is found output is nothing. Should be self explained to check if nothing is found.

## Much more normal not really pythonic

Give you the matched string, too

```
given = 'Iamfoothegreat'.lower()
targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'other']

dct = {'pos' : - 1, 'string' : None};
given = given.lower()

for t in targets:
    i = given.find(t)
    if i > -1 and (i < list['pos'] or list['pos'] == -1):
        dct['pos'] = i;
        dct['string'] = t;

print dct
```

Output is:

```
{'pos': 3, 'string': 'foo'}
```

If element is not found:

```
{'pos': -1, 'string': None}
```

## Performance Comparision of both

with this string and pattern

```
given = "hello world" * 5000
given += "grea" + given
targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'other']
```

1000 loops with timeit:

```
regex approach: 4.08629107475 sec for 1000
normal approach: 1.80048894882 sec for 1000
```

10 loops. Now with much bigger targets (targets * 1000):

```
normal approach: 4.06895017624 for 10
regex approach: 34.8153910637 for 10
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should use `re.escape` on each target before building the pattern.

Comment: @ekhumoro ok thats right. Thanks for that, I fixed it.

Comment: One other thing: it is simpler to use `re.search(pattern, ...)`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham. It either returns a `match` object, or `None`.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham it has then a MatchObject and prints 0 and the match

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Could you speed test my algorithm, too. Would be interesting with your testcase! So we can just compare.

Comment: I will throw a more comprehensive test together when the OP replies

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the regex version looks fast but its damn slow. I compared both of my functions. Thanks for editing, and the tip with the one answer per question. Like your answer!

Comment: @Kordi, I threw a quick test in with the rest, a regex can be fast for certain things but not really suited for this case, you could probably move the compile out if the test but it would not change the timing significantly

Comment: @PadraicCunningham tried this but is not really faster, but damn pretty to read, i think

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
answer = min([given.lower().find(x.lower()) for x in targets 
    if x.lower() in given.lower()] or [0])
```

**Demo 1**

```
given = 'Iamfoothegreat'
targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'other']

answer = min([given.lower().find(x.lower()) for x in targets 
    if x.lower() in given.lower()] or [0])
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
3
```

**Demo 2**

```
given = 'this is a different string'
targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'other']

answer = min([given.lower().find(x.lower()) for x in targets 
    if x.lower() in given.lower()] or [0])
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
0
```

I also think that the following solution is quite readable:

```
given = 'the string'
targets = ('foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'other')

given = given.lower()

for i in range(len(given)):
    if given.startswith(targets, i):
        print i
        break
else:
    print -1
```

Comment: The OP wants to ignore case.

Comment: @padraiccunningham I've just added an alternative solution - would love to see it added to your list of time comparisons!

Comment: @gtlambert, you need to pass a tuple to str.startswith, I can show you the result but you may not  like it!

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks - I've just been testing myself and it isn't pretty!

Comment: It is hard to beat index or find, even from a complexity standpoint I have seen code written using exclusively using pure python get hammered by the efficiency of things like list.count find etc.. even when you are talking linear vs quadratic.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fairly good, but you can make it a little more efficient by moving the `.lower` conversion out of the loop: there's no need to repeat it for each target substring. The code can be condensed a little using list comprehensions, although that doesn't necessarily make it faster. I use a nested list comp to avoid calling `given.find(t)` twice for each `t`.

I've wrapped my code in a function for easier testing.

```
def min_match(given, targets):
    given = given.lower()
    a = [i for i in [given.find(t) for t in targets] if i > -1]
    return min(a) if a else None

targets = ['foo', 'bar', 'grea', 'othe']

data = (
    'Iamfoothegreat', 
    'IAMFOOTHEGREAT', 
    'Iamfothgrease',
    'Iamfothgret',
)

for given in data:
    print(given, min_match(given, targets))
```

**output**

```
Iamfoothegreat 3
IAMFOOTHEGREAT 3
Iamfothgrease 7
Iamfothgret None
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def getFirst(given,targets):
    try:
        return min([i for x in targets for i in [given.find(x)] if not i == -1])
    except ValueError:
        return 0
```

Comment: Two calls to `given.find()` doesn't make a very efficient solution.

Comment: OP asked for a pythonic way.

Comment: He also said that his problem with his own is that it is inefficient.  Besides, is inefficiency Pythonic?

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but as zondo said, the two calls to `.find(x)` is less efficient than the OP's code.  Also, the OP wants case-insensitive matching. BTW, you can pass `min` a generator expression instead of a  list comprehension.

Comment: If you call `min` on `[]` you get a `ValueError`.